# Google Search App sends notification 'at this shop?' in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, geofencing

I want to use some of the google search app's feature, you will get my question if you have ever seen a notification stating 'at this shop?' on your status bar while visiting any shop, i want to know that how google knows that i am at this particular shop, does it getting the locations everytime and check for the current location and sends the notification or it is using the geofencing for every shop so that it is notified, i don't know what are they using for sending that specific notification with optimisation.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking for is location based updates and particular activity based callbacks, you can try using the Awareness API by Google which is well documented [here](https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview).

The awareness api provides 2 end points, `Fence` API and `Snapshot` API which gives location based updates.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me after researching this api for 2 days, it fulfilled my requirement

Comment: But i need some help here, i have used this api as when i stopped walking i am getting the nearby places from the current location, the problem is i have tested it in real time, while going on a walk. but i need to test this thing multiple times, so can you tell me how do i simulate this walking things or activity recognition things, i have used mock locations for testing but that did not worked, could you please help me out

Comment: Try googling stuff. I dont have hands on experience on the Awareness api. Check this link [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjokILi9MnWAhUBN48KHee-BpAQFggyMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Finthecheesefactory.com%2Fblog%2Fgoogle-awareness-api-in-action%2Fen&usg=AFQjCNH3uSxgDbN0GeodMvzi0cfi9TDKJw)